# running a script on startup and have it restart if crashed in debian

Tags: service, debian, startup

I have program that I need to run at startup in the background, so far I have it in rc.local like so:

```
sudo ./simple_program &
```

However this does not take into consideration if the program crashes. I need it so that whenever the program crashes, it is restarted again.

I think the approach is to write a bash script and run that instead in rc.local, where the bash script calls the simple_program and reruns it if needed. However, I'm not quite sure exactly what to do here. Could someone provide me a template?

Answer (score 0):

Try with [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) or [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html), they are specifically designed to supervise other processes